# SQL IN clause with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
CREATE TABLE student_marks (Name, Subject, Marks ) AS
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Physics',   20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Bio',       20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Chemistry', 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Physics',   24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Bio',       24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Chemistry', 24 FROM DUAL;
```

I want to get the name and marks of Mike for Physics and for all the subjects for Ryan. Query I want to use is something like this

```
select *
from   student_marks
where  (Name,Subject) in (('Mike','Physics'),('Ryan',*));
```

What should I replace * in the query so that it matches all the subjects for Ryan?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `*` with `Subject`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed96a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE student_marks (Name, Subject, Marks ) AS
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Physics',   20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Bio',       20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike', 'Chemistry', 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Physics',   24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Bio',       24 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ryan', 'Chemistry', 24 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from   student_marks
where (Name,Subject) in (('Mike','Physics'),('Ryan',Subject))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed96a/1/0)**:

```
| NAME |   SUBJECT | MARKS |
|------|-----------|-------|
| Mike |   Physics |    20 |
| Ryan |   Physics |    24 |
| Ryan |       Bio |    24 |
| Ryan | Chemistry |    24 |
```